# Cookies and Hidden Security Values in curl

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I am trying to log in to a site using PHP/curl in order to be able to access data that is only available to registered users on the site. The form requests an email, password, and a hidden security value. The security value is randomly generated with each login page load. I think this is causing my problem: in the below script, curl first requests the page, the code parses the security value, and then curl attempts to log in. However, as I have verified using print_r, the security code will have changed for the second page load.

Here is the code:

```
$email = urlencode("emailhandleIuse");
$password = "myPassword";
$loginURL = "https://www.example.com/login/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginURL);
$ch = setCurlParameters($ch);
$securityCode = curl_exec($ch);
$securityCode = urlencode(scrape_between($securityCode, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"security\" value=\"","\" />")); // gets security value from the page HTML
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email='.$email.'&password='.$password.'&security='.$securityCode);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.example.com/followingpage");
$secondPage = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

function setCurlParameters($ch) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    return $ch;
}

function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){   
    $data = stristr($data, $start); // Stripping all data from before $start
    $data = substr($data, strlen($start));  // Stripping $start
    $stop = stripos($data, $end);   // Getting the position of the $end of the data to scrape
    $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);    // Stripping all data from after and including the $end of the data to scrape
    return $data;   // Returning the scraped data from the function
    }
```

$secondPage winds up being a login page because I am not validating after posting the details I think are needed.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After doing the first request, you have to close the curl handle, otherwise the cookie will not be stored into the file. That's why your second request (login) is not forwarding the cookie to server.

```
curl_close($ch);
```

For cookie file, better to use full path `c:/tmp/cookie.txt` when you are running from the server (i think).

By the way, using Verbose mode you can see yourself what is actually happening!

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
```